# Knockoutjs click and edit field not updating observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockoutjs to implement a simple click and edit system.  The value seems to be updating correctly if I change the input focus, but I can't seem to get the value to update when I use a keypress event binding: http://jsfiddle.net/rxYGz/11/

```
        function Item(label, value)   
{    
this.label = ko.observable(label);
this.value = ko.observable(value);

this.editing = ko.observable(false);

this.editItem = function(e) {
    this.editing(true);
}

this.checkEditDone = function(e,f) {

    if (e.which == 13)
    {
        this.editing(false);
    }
    else
    return true;
};

return this;      
};

var SimpleViewModel = {

editItem: function(item) {
  item.editing(true);
},

templateToUse: function(item) {
  return item.editing() ? 'editTmpl' : 'viewTmpl';
},

title : ko.observable(new Item('Request Title', 'EDIT THIS TITLE')),

product_line : ko.observable(new Item('Product Line', 'EDIT THIS LINE'))
};

ko.applyBindings(SimpleViewModel);
```

Bindings:

```
<ul class='list'>
    <div class='header'>Request</div>
    <li data-bind="template: {name: templateToUse, data: title}"></li>
    <li data-bind="template: {name: templateToUse, data: product_line}"></li>
</ul>

<script id='editTmpl' type='text/html'>
<span data-bind="text: label">&nbsp</span>
<input data-bind="value: value, valueupdate: 'change', hasfocus:editing, event: {keypress: checkEditDone}"/>
</script>

<script id='viewTmpl' type='text/html'>
<span data-bind="text: label">&nbsp</span>
<span style='margin-left:10px;color:maroon' data-bind="text: value, click: function() {editItem()}">&nbsp</span>     
</script>
```

It seems like this should work, but I'm obviously not understanding something.

Comment: It might be a browser-specific implementation, but I got your fiddle to work in Firefox by binding to keyup instead of keypress.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd included the html snippet.  Changing from "keypress' to "keyup" seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

The textbox change event is fired only on blur. You'll want to use keydown instead of change.

Second, the the valueUpdate binding is case sensitive. Use valueUpdate, not valueupdate.

Here's an [updated fiddle that fixes these problems](http://jsfiddle.net/rxYGz/14/).